# Need help using Python to parse log file

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

I'm having a problem with a Python script I'm working on that searches a log file for occurances of a text string and if found prints them to another file, I have tried using break but that ends the process and I end up with only one entry in the other file, if I don't use break, it applies the ending statement to all lines not containing the text, basically I want to end up with a logfile with all occurances of the text contained in it, if the text does not occur in any of the lines in the source logfile I want only one line printed to the new logfile saying that nothing was found, this is the code I am trying now -

```
with open("/var/log/syslog", "r") as vpnfile:
    for line in vpnfile:
        if "failed CHAP" in line:
            print (line,)
        elif "failed CHAP" not in line:    
            continue
        else:
            print ("Nadda")
```

Comment: If this is more than homework, you might be interested in David Beasly's [*Generator Trick for Systems Programmers*](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/). The slide presentation is quite good and there are oodles of examples. His [Talks page](http://www.dabeaz.com/talks.html) points to other tasty bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
found = []
with open("/var/log/syslog", "r") as vpnfile:
    for line in vpnfile:
        if "failed CHAP" in line:
            found.append(line)
        # no need to check if "failed CHAP" is not in the line, since you
        # already know it's not there from the first test failing
if found:
    print(" ".join(found))
else:
    print("Nadda")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to give the same results I was already getting with other iterations, i.e., the lines I'm looking for get printed to the file, but so does the last statement, I need the last statement printed only if no occurances of the text are found.

Comment: Not a problem.  This can almost certainly be done more concisely, but happy to help get you moving again.